# PDF validate using PDFBOX PreflightParser for PDDocument

Tags: java, pdfbox

I could like to validate the pdf that was created(not as a file) but as ByteArrayOutputStream which is downloaded to browser . In order to avoid security issue could like to validate using pdfbox preflightparser where it has option only for parsing file not PDDocument.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
PreflightParser parser = new PreflightParser(doc);
```

//this constructor accepts only file.

Expectation is validate pdf file on the fly instead of loading from system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also pass a `DataSource`. To facilitate this, use `org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.ByteArrayDataSource` whose constructor accepts an `InputStream`.

Comment: I was able to achieve it using this construct but it fails to parse a encrypted file with below error.

`PreflightParser parser = new PreflightParser(new ByteArrayDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent)));`

**Error**
The file is not valid, error(s) :
1.0 : Syntax error, Cannot decrypt PDF, the password is incorrect.

Any idea how to pass password like we do for PDDocument load.

Comment: https://www.pdfa.org/pdfa-faq/ "PDF/A prohibits the use of encryption on the file"

Comment: ok Got it.. But wondering how this is really possible in real world without password protected pdf to be PDF/A-1 compliant.

Comment: The best would be to use the CreatePDFA example from the source code download, and expand from there. Becoming PDF/A-1b compliant is not difficult if you start from scratch.

Comment: I think i have not communicated what i thought. Any password protected PDF cannot be PDF/A-1 compliant right ? so, In real scenarios this appears all password protected PDF's are not complaint.

Comment: Indeed. It makes sense when you think about it: PDF/A is meant for long-term storage, and PDF files should contain all that is needed to be opened and shown. See also wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need extra information PreflightParser can give you - you can use [PDFParser](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser.html). It's constructor accepts [RandomAccessBuffer](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/io/RandomAccessBuffer.html) which takes `byte[]` to create.

Comment: In that case, I rather recommend to use `PDDocument.load(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()).close()`.